# How to make this PostgreSQL query faster?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

This is the table:

```
dt VARCHAR(65)
ct VARCHAR(65)
amount INT
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN dt='peter' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) 
FROM receipt WHERE dt='peter' OR ct='peter'
```

I have 800k records in the table. And I have indexes on `dt`, `ct`, `amount`, and `ct,dt`. At the moment this query takes over 5 minutes (!).

Comment: Show us the execution plan (ideally as `explain analyze`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT SUM(s) AS ss
FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) AS s
      FROM receipt
      WHERE dt = 'peter'
      UNION
      SELECT -SUM(amount)
      FROM receipt
      WHERE dt = 'peter')
```

This query should run faster than your original one. Otherwise you should normalize the dt/ct columns to use joins for better performance